# Cycles: How to apply procedurally made material to a single face properly?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, procedural

I have a procedurally made material that displays single digit "1" using Generated Texture Coordinate as input to Mapping.

Now I want to apply this material to a single Face.
With Generated it's not working (obviously because Generated coordinates represent the whole object).

So I tried to pick the necessary Face, Unwrap it to separate UV map, added UV Map Node to the Node Editor, picked that map and used it as input to Mapping. Material is shown incorrectly (partially). I've tried various scaling of the UV map, but still somehow I can't get all the parts of the material to appear on the Face. I've tried to play with Mapping Node by changing X and Z Locations - still no effect (however it does still shift X correctly). How may I solve it?

In short: I want my procedural digit to be shown on a single Face exactly like on a whole single plane. Thank you!

Update: here is how it looks. Left side = solid cube with material applied (Generated input). Right side = rectangle of few faces with material applied to single one).[image: sample view]

**Update2**: All right, looks like I solved the problem. So the thing is when you switch from Generated mapping coordinates to UV Map former Z axis (in my case) becomes Y axis (presumably due to UV map being in XY plane), so I just had to substitute Y from SeparateXYZ Node as Z input to my "drawing" Node.
Thanks all who attended!

Comment: Share your blend file it seems, though, you need to rescale texture.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the material to a single face?

Comment: I did exactly that, I made up a vertex group for that face and applied material to it leaving the rest of the object with another material. Plus added that UV map representing face proportions (it's rectangular anyway).

Comment: Have you tried using a mapping node to adjust x,y,z?